# Convert JSON to Map

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, json

I want to store key and value for the following json dynamically.

```
Key as "01u9000000Ag0bbAAB" and value as "203"

String input = '[{"01u9000000Ag0bbAAB":"203","01u9000000Ag0bZAAR":"23","Id":"00k0w000003HeFhAAK"}]';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the ***JSON.deserializeUntyped(String)*** method for this .

```
String input = '[{"01u9000000Ag0bbAAB":"203","01u9000000Ag0bZAAR":"23","Id":"00k0w000003HeFhAAK"}]';
List<Object> lst = (List<Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonInput);
```

Get the key and values

```
for(Object o : lst) {
    Map<String,Object> mapObject = (Map<String,Object>)o;
      for(String key : mapObject.keyset()) {
         system.debug('key' + key);
         system.debug('key value' + (String)m.get(key));
      }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Mohit. I tried this one. I getting this error System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type List<ANY> to Map<String,ANY>

Comment: I got this error  "Loop must iterate over collection: Map<String,Object>" on this line for(Map<String,Object> mapObject : (Map<String,Object>)(o))

Comment: fixed the typo there . Try now

Comment: Thanks Mohit. Now it's working fine.